# Cant understand this arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to understand this.

```
const btns = (category) => {
  const newdata = data.filter((data) => data.category === category)
  setDta(newdata)
}
```

How I did similarly and the way I want to understand.

```
const btns = (category) => {
    const dtn = () => {
      data.filter((category) => {
        if (data.category === category) {
          return setDta(dtn)
        }
      })
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to understand what your question is.

Comment: `return` in a `filter()` doesn't stop filtering. The first form gets an array result. The second one calls `setDta()` with...a function? It's not clear what you're doing there. You define a function that defines a function that doesn't get called in this snippet, so it basically does nothing.

Comment: I want to understand that arrow function(first). I tried to make it simple(2nd one) and understandable but it doesnt work. I want to understand the first arrow function in a simple way like the second one.

Comment: The first one is effectively `function btns(category) { .... }` while the second is too confused, it doesn't do anything. The first one can be expressed as a a plain `function` since there's no references to `this` in it.

Comment: @Roshan I don't think you understand the second one. What I see is a fork-bomb. At least almost, `data.category === category` will probably never be `true`, and `dtn` is never called in the first place in your snippet.

Comment: I think you may find your answer here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your original code:

```
const btns = (category) => {
  const newdata = data.filter((data) => data.category === category)
  setDta(newdata)
}
```

I'm going to first change an argument name to avoid some confusion in the explanation so it's like this (this doesn't change the output, just makes it less confusing to understand):

```
const btns = (category) => {
  const newdata = data.filter((item) => item.category === category)
  setDta(newdata)
}
```

This does the following steps:

1. Creates a function named `btns`
2. That accepts a `category` as an argument
3. When that function is called, it then filters an array named `data` which is not defined here so it must be defined in some higher scope.
4. To create a new array that only contains the items whose `.category` property matches the category that was passed in
5. And assigns that result to a variable named `newdata`
6. And, then calls `setDta(newData)` to pass that newly filtered array to a function named `setDta()`.

---

Your second code block does not actually do anything lasting or have any result.  It creates a `btn` function that, when called defines a local function named `dtn()`, but never calls it and then returns.  That local function `dtn()` is then garbage collected without ever being used.

Answer (score 0):

This abstraction you are creating obfuscates your code : what would a function named `btns` and taking a string as parameter do? This makes no sense and forces the reader to look up the implementation and then they would wonder where this free variable `data` comes from and wonder what it is (everything is data)

Now I don't like your `setDta` either, but I take it you don't have a choice (you could be using React/useState)

I propose that you isolate your predicate like so

```
const matchCategory = category => item => 
    item.category === category;

const filteredByFoo = data.filter(matchCategory('foo'))
setDta(filteredByFoo);
```

This is very composable. You could create a bunch of reusable functions to clean up the call site

```
const filterByCategory = category => items =>
    items.filter(matchCategory(category));
  
const filterByFoo = filterByCategory('foo');

setDta(filterByFoo(data));
```

Now the above would be better written like so but I didn't want to confuse you

```
import {filter, compose} from 'utils';

const filterByCategory = compose(filter, matchCategory);
  
const filterByFoo = filterByCategory('foo');

setDta(filterByFoo(data));
```

when I read `filterByFoo(data)` there is zero ambiguity.